# I am trying to run the CUDA example but i have problems with openGL (libGLEW.a) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, cuda, nsight

I am trying to run the bilateral filter example in the standard cuda examples on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Nsight Eclipse Edition.It performs a simple bilateral filter on an image and uses OpenGL to display the results.

All the examples that don't use openGL work fine so i guess the cuda installations worked, but this one that uses openGL and another one still with openGL I tried do not.

I always get this error while building:

```
make: ***  No rule to make target "/usr/samples/common/lib/linux/x86_64/libGLEW.a", needed for "exampleImg". Stop. exampleImg C/C++ Problem
```

I noticed that the path in the error is not where *libGLEW.a* is but i don't know how to change it in the makefile or if that would fix the problem

I also looked in the findgllib.mk file in the example directory to check if the cuda version was right (which is right) and if i could change the directory there with no success.

What could be the issue?

EDIT: I solved the problem the solution is written below as a comment. Now I have a problem with uchar4 seen as ambiguous in the cpp files, but that's another story

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by going to `Project->Properties->Build->Settings->Tool Settings->NVCC Linker->Miscellaneous` and changing the path under "Other Objects" to the path to `libGLEW.a` found in the samples area. Now, if I build, I get no error and it runs.